# Google maps API GroundOverlay jumps horizontally between "world-tiles"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The effect can be seen here:
http://ec2-23-22-99-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

When the page loads and the map is centered somewhere in the Atlantic... everything looks good.

However if we're to drag the map view overtop of India ... the map jumps to the other "world-tile" ( giving it a name :P )

```
var vegtype_bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-59,-176.8), // south-west
  new google.maps.LatLng(84,179) // north-east
);
var vegtype = new google.maps.GroundOverlay( '../vegtype_overlay.png', vegtype_bounds, overlayOptions );
```

As the code shows it is a rather large overlay ... but I'd love to either

- have the whole thing tile across all horizontal instances of the world map
- restrict it to remain on the map which is used on page load ( instead of jumping between the x-axis tiled maps )

Comment: A bit of js fiddle testing to show another simple example of the image jumping http://jsfiddle.net/Dj4rt/

Comment: Split the single map overlay into tiles.  The v3 API is built for tile support, not so much larger single-file overlays.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I did in the end. It's a shame that you have to do this though...